# How to retrieve data from database in php code

Tags: php, mysql

There are a lots of error in my code but I don't know which one of the error.

I'm trying to retrieve data from database and paste it into html but there are problem reading table. There are two tables from database one of it are diagnostic table and another one is diagnostic answer. The table of diagnostic contain 10 question and each question had 3 multiple choices answer that I put in diagnostic answer table. I'm also try to loop the question from the diagnostic table same as the answer.

```
<form name="question" action="diagnostic_test_process.php" method="post">`

<fieldset>
<table><?PHP      

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM diagnostic")
or die ("Problem reading table:". mysql_error());
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)){ ?>

<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
   <label for="question"></label>
      <?PHP                                
        echo "<p>".$result["id_diagnostic"].".";
        echo $result["question"]."</p>"; ?>
   </td>
</tr>

 <?php
 $sql=mysql_query
 ("SELECT a.id_answer, a.answer FROM diagnostic_answer a, diagnostic b WHERE a.id_diagnostic = b.id_diagnostic and a.id_diagnostic= " . $result["ïd_diagnostic"])          
 or die ("Problem reading table:". mysql_error());
 while ($value= mysql_fetch_array ($sql)){  ?>

<tr>
   <td>
     <label for="answer"></label>
     <p><input id=<?php echo $answer['id_answer']; ?> type='radio' name='answer' value='1' onClick="calculate()">
     <?php echo $value['answer']; ?></p>
   </td>
</tr>

<?php } 
// close recordset
?>
<?php } ?>

    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: how to do the recordset..anyone know? ;)

Comment: i don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Please tell us what is the problem with your code (comparing what you expected, and what you got), and if you have got error messages. This will improve your question, and help others help you. The [Help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) may be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

the error is here.

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)){
```

it should be

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

or

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc ($sql)){
```

don't forget to do the same for the 2nd while loop you have in there

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit some of your code, see the code and tried to figure it out. you should go to youtube search some tutorial for reference.

```html
<form name="question" action="diagnostic_test_process.php" method="post">`

<fieldset>
<table><?PHP      
mysql_fetch_array ($sql);//This is the issue, don't know what you want

//$result need to be defined here

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM diagnostic"
while $result = put a defined string here ); 

include the html inside the php loop

echo "<tr>"; //do like this for all below html code
   <td colspan="2">
   <label for="question"></label>
      <?PHP                                
        echo "<p>".$result["id_diagnostic"].".";
        echo $result["question"]."</p>"; ?>
   </td>
</tr>

  
  ?>
  
  
  
 <?php
 $sql=mysql_query
 ("SELECT a.id_answer, a.answer FROM diagnostic_answer a, diagnostic b WHERE a.id_diagnostic = b.id_diagnostic and a.id_diagnostic= " . $result["ïd_diagnostic"])          
 or die ("Problem reading table:". mysql_error());
 while ($value= mysql_fetch_array ($sql)){  ?>

<tr>
   <td>
     <label for="answer"></label>
     <p><input id=<?php echo $answer['id_answer']; ?> type='radio' name='answer' value='1' onClick="calculate()">
     <?php echo $value['answer']; ?></p>
   </td>
</tr>

<?php } 
// close recordset
?>
<?php } ?>

    </table>
</fieldset>
```